# button -command in for loop (no such variable)

Tags: tcl

I've got this small loop cycle in TCL

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= $user} {incr i} {
   grid [ttk::button .seluser.$i -text "$i" -command { set ::user $i }] -column $i -row 1
}
```

and I'm getting the message

> ERROR can't read "i": no such variable

I think it's because `-command` works like a new proc and that's why it can not identify the variable `i`.

I don't know how to do it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try quotes instead of braces, so that `$i` is pre-interpolated.  For example,

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= $user} {incr i} {
    grid [ttk::button .seluser.$i -text "$i" -command " set ::user $i "] -column $i -row 1
}
```

Comment: It is recommended practice to use `list` to construct define-time substituted commands, like this: `[list set ::user $i]`. This is recommended because it is both systematically guaranteed to be correct (Tcl likes to build lists that are also substitution-free commands) and faster to execute (basically, the value can carry a proof with it that no parsing is required).

Comment: It would be good to discuss *why* quotes work instead of braces